# Lua: is a function closure a local function?

Tags: lua, closures, local

Suppose I have the following Lua code:

```
function f(v)
    function g()
        return v * v
    end
    return g
end
```

Obviously, 'g' in the above Lua code forms a closure. What I am wondering is: is 'g' a "local" function by default?

Do I have to explicitly add the 'local' keyword before 'function g()' to make 'g' truly local? If without explicit 'local', and if 'g' thus is a "global", how would anyone access 'g' from an outer scope? I am suspicious that I could do "f.g" in order to access 'g' in this context.

If 'g' is "local" by default, then what's the point of allowing "local" to be prefixing the function definition (closure) inside a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alrighty, I think I've got an answer by myself:

Without prefixing the closure 'g' with the 'local' keyword, 'g' is actually a global! Because function declaration essentially an assignment of an anonymous function to a named variable in Lua! So the closure definition in the above code is equivalent to:

```
function f(v)
    g = function()
        return v * v
    end
    return g
end
```

And according to Lua variable scoping rule, any variable not explicitly tagged with 'local' is a global, so basically 'g' becomes a global function, and I believe anyone can just call module.g() without any problems!

Prefixing 'local' to 'g' makes it a true local variable that there is no way to access it accidentally outside 'f'.

Comment: And, yes, all functions are anonymous. Any number of variables (globals, locals, fields) can be referencing a function value at a particular time.

Comment: To clarify, functions are values. Values are not scoped; Variables are. So, "'g' becomes a global function" isn't quite right. 'g' is bound to the global scope at compile-time. At run-time, each time that bit of code is executed (if ever), 'g' is assigned a newly created function value from the evaluation of the function definition expression.